# Most viewed count always zero

Tags: views, nodes

I try to adapt my Views block, I add Node Statistics: total views
but it always show Zero, what am I doing wrong? sth is missing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Verify if you have enabled “Count content views” within Statistics module configuration.
(`admin/config/system/statistics` for D7)

Comment: I found the problem  
**www.website.com/admin/reports/settings**
The option was disabled there, I enabled and now its counting

Comment: **Reports -> Access log settings** in D6